# Can connections on a principal bundle have torsion?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections

In Riemannian geometry, one defines torsion and curvature for the affine/metric connection. Is it possible to define a torsion form for a connection which is defined on a principle G-bundle?

Any references would really be appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: We can only define torsion for affine connections *on the tangent bundle*, where the directions we can differentiate in and the things we are differentiating are interchangeable. Perhaps if your $G$-bundle is associated to the tangent bundle in some sense (e.g. the tangent frame bundle) there will be some incarnation of torsion, but certainly not in general. Curvature (as you're probably aware) makes sense and is a standard topic.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis What about the torsion of the spin connection? Is it defined on the spinor bundle or just the tangent bundle?

Comment: I don't really know anything about spinors, so I'll leave it to someone else to answer. I strongly suspect they fall under my "associated to the tangent bundle" caveat, since spinors are constructed using the tangent frame bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The curvature of a connection defined on a principal bundle is the covariant derivative of the connection form.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)#Curvature_form